# If A is the adjacency matrix for a graph g, what is the length of the shortest path from node i to node j in g?

Tags: algorithm, performance, graph, time-complexity

**Choices :**
 1. The length of the shortest path *is* A[i,j].
 2. The length of the shortest path *is* the smallest non-negative integer k such that (A[i,j])^k is non-zero. 
 3. The length of the shortest path *is* the largest non-negative integer k such that (A^k)[i,j] is zero.
 4. The length of the shortest path *is*  the smallest non-negative integer k such that (A^k)[i,j] is non-zero.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is

> 4. The length of the shortest path is the smallest non-negative integer k such that (A^k)[i,j] is non-zero.

- `A[i,j] = A^1[i,j]` - the number of paths of length 1 from i to j. (1
  if there is an edge, 0 otherwise)
- `A^2[i,j]` - the number of paths of length 2 from i to j
- ...
- `A^k[i,j]` - the number of paths of length k from i to j

When you find `k` such that `A^k[i,j]` is not zero, it means there is a path from `i` to `j` of length `k`.

---

I'll show the reasoning for `A^2`, and you can follow the logic and use induction to show it for all `k`.

From definition of matrix multiplication:

```
A^2[i,j] = A[i,1] * A{1,j] + ... + A[i,k]*A[k,j] + ... + A[i,n]*A[n,j]
```

But for any given `k` what does `A[i,k]*A[k,j]` mean? `A[i,k] = 1` if there is an edge from `i` to `k`, and 0 otherwise. Similarly for `A[k,j]`. This means the term `A[i,k]*A[k,j]` will add 1 to the summation if and only if there are edges `(i,k)` and `(k,j)` - which create a path of length 2 from `i` to `j`.